# How should one handle a recruiter emailing you about an obviously irrelevant job?

Tags: professionalism, recruitment

I've spent my entire career as a software engineer. Every once in awhile, a recruiter will email me about some obviously irrelevant job. For example, I recently had a recruiter email me about a housekeeping job; I also have people email me periodically about jobs like administrative assistants (no experience at all in that area) or project management jobs (again, no relevant experience at all).

What's the proper way to handle this situation?

Comment: I deleted my profile, from whatever service they were using, Linkedin was the biggest offender so I made my profile private. Any recruiter email that does not have specifics, like the company name or a specific salary range being offered, is immediately deleted.  If they have access to my profile, they likely have access to my current resume, so they should know exactly what they would be willing to offer me.  **If they are not willing to do that, then it's not a legitimate recruiter, and I don't choose to be somebody's wet noodle on some random person's kitchen cabinet**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ignore them. It is most likely spam. You're going to get a lot of spam during your career. They obviously didn't take the time to read your profile or know anything about you. You aren't under any obligation to respond to anyone that is wasting your time. Send their message to your spam folder.

Comment: Agreed. There are recruiter emails that you're not interested in, but which merit a polite "no thank you." And then there are recruiter emails that merit nothing more than a swift click on the "delete" button. These sound like they fit in the second group.

Answer (score 3):

Recruiters are basically spammers nowadays. They probably sent the same message you got to other 1000 profiles. Just ignore them and move on.

Answer (score 2):

If they are from a company you may wish to join in future as a software engineer or your future profile, I would suggest to send a quick response eg. "Thank you for contacting however I am not looking for change at the moment, I wish you the best with your search. Have a great rest of the day!"

> I recently had a recruiter email me about a housekeeping job

Specifically, for situations like these when they are reaching you for completely irrelevant profiles, you can ignore them completely. I know, its difficult to ignore and I think that is why you posted this question, so here are some more suggestions:

**First of all**, It's a little strange that the recruiters are reaching out to you for completely irrelevant profiles, so not a 100 percent sure if there's some scope of improvement in your registered profile on the job sites.

**2nd option** – if you are not actively looking for job switch, you can turn off notifications and go into private mode on job search websites.

**3rd option** – you can create an email id specifically for job search websites and update your accounts so that those emails are only going on that email id (created specifically for job sites) and you are getting notifications.

**Pros of 3rd option**
You wont be worried about recruiters emails anymore because with other options you can only limit them to a certain point of extent.

**Cons of 3rd option**
You may miss some good opportunities :)

**4th option** –In the headline of your profile, you can write something like this – I am not looking for change and do not wish to be contacted for opportunities other than Software Engineering roles. If not 100 percent, it may help to some extent!

Hope this helps, best of luck!